# Python 3 Tensorflow Object detection API No such File or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I was trying to train a model with my own class in tensorflow object detection api. 
I use anaconda with Python 3.5, tensorflow 1.4.0. The example detection works. What I don't understand is which file is actually missing (or which directory) since the error is not actually providing it.

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=/home/mace/Documents/Python/cvtennis/tensorflow/models/train/ --pipleline_config=/home/mace/Documents/Python/cvtennis/tensorflow/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/mace/anaconda3/envs/tf_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train.py", line 110, in main
    overwrite=True)
  File "/home/mace/anaconda3/envs/tf_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 385, in copy
    compat.as_bytes(oldpath), compat.as_bytes(newpath), overwrite, status)
  File "/home/mace/anaconda3/envs/tf_35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ; No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems to work with Tensoflow 1.3.0

Comment: Hi sir! I also have the same problem, how did you solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I just downgraded from 1.4.0 to 1.3.0.